# Issues in node template naming in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I am trying to override the template of a node in drupal 6. For example I had a content type called purchase. For that I created node-purchase.tpl.php to override the template and it worked. I had another content type called user_account_map. For that I created node-user_account_map.tpl.php. However, it doesn't seem to work in this case. What should be the name of the template in the second case. I have cleared the caches and all to see if it is because of the cache but it isn't. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

node-user_account_map.tpl.php instead rename it to node-user-account-map.tpl.php and clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, try installing the [Devel Themer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer), which will display your options for naming theme files. See the [screencast and tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/209561) for examples.